# Hibernate daily builds

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Are there daily builds of Hibernate that I can download?  I need the latest version for a [bug fix](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3636) that isn't in the released versions. I'm currently trying to build the latest version but am running in to all sorts of test case failures. If would be faster if there's a daily build that I just download and use.

Answer (score 0):

If there are test-case failures I would say you probably don't want a nightly build.  Who knows what else will be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just use the source control repositories from the main site's download page: http://www.hibernate.org/6.html#A4

Comment: If a project doesn't compile binaries already in the nightly build process, then it usually isn't done by someone else for public release--wouldn't make sense to bother with that. However, the source should be setup to build yourself without any configuration or anything.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you said you *did* try the source code and you got test errors. That's why their not release candidates yet I guess. You could try to find the patch for the specific bug, and merge it with the source code of the last release build. Again, that still could give you errors.